# How to use AP and Managed wifi?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, access-point, hostapd

**How can I use wifi connections as an access point  while at the same time connecting to an existing wifi network ?**

My experiment:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add uap0 type __ap
service dnsmasq restart
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Output:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to create interface mon.uap0: -95 (Operation not supported)
uap0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface uap0 with hwaddr b8:27:a1:0f:00:00 and ssid "TESTAP"
Failed to set beacon parameters
uap0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Interface initialization failed
uap0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
uap0: AP-DISABLED
uap0: Unable to setup interface.
uap0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
uap0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface uap0 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=uap0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
interface=uap0
ssid=TESTAP
hw_mode=g
channel=10
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=123456789a
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_group_rekey=86400
ieee80211n=1
wme_enabled=1
```

Comment: IIRC from posts I have seen it can work, but you have to use the same channel for client and AP. And I think people mentioned that performance was not great. See e.g. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138730#p936518 (topic runs over several pages)

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr b8:27:eb:ff:00:00
        type managed
        wiphy 0
        channel 4 (2427 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2427 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm`
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iw uap0 info
Interface uap0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x3
        addr b8:27:eb:ff:00:00
        type AP
        wiphy 0
        channel 4 (2427 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2427 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm`  I did same channel but i got same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do three steps:

1. create a virtual interface `ap0` for the access point
2. start access point daemon `hostapd` using interface `ap0`
3. start `wpa_supplicant` for wifi client using interface `wlan0`

You have to do it exactly in this order otherwise the setup will fail. I have seen many attempts to achieve this including restarting services in order with special conditions. I prefer to use *systemd* because you can define dependencies when services have to start. So you can configure it in a clean order. How to do this in detail you can look at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/89803/79866).

Comment: Thanks It's worked. But My iptables rules don't work on hotspot. Can u help me? [how-does-iptables-rules-table-work-with-hotspo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88506/how-does-iptables-rules-table-work-with-hotspot)

Comment: @a.gulcan Sorry I'm not so familiar with iptables. But iptables is a firewall and usually used to restrict connections. If you want a firewall then from your working access point you can restrict it step by step.

Comment: I can't reset hostapd.service. is there a way to solve this problem? except reboot

Comment: @a.gulcan What do you mean with *reset hostapd*? I have updated the link in my answer. If you follow it you can stop, start and restart **hostapd**. Please read the section **Conclusion**.